# Flask Admin App files seperation

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm wondering how to separate the app into different files, I know what the files but I'm wondering which aspects of the code goes were,so I currently have,
FlaskAdmin/
   Static/
   Templates/
   ---App.py

FlaskAdmin/
          ---Config
          ---Run
  App/
    -Static/
    -Templates/
    ---Views
    ---Models
    ---**Int**
    ---Forms
    ---Decorators

```
    import os
import os.path as op
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from wtforms import validators

import flask_admin as admin
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import filters


# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

# Create in-memory database
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Create models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


# Create M2M table
post_tags_table = db.Table('post_tags', db.Model.metadata,
                           db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')),
                           db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
                           )


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='posts')

    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=post_tags_table)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UserInfo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    key = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String(64))

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='info')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.key, self.value)


class Tree(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tree.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Tree', remote_side=[id], backref='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


# Customized User model admin
class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    inline_models = (UserInfo,)


# Customized Post model admin
class PostAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    # Visible columns in the list view
    column_exclude_list = ['text']

    # List of columns that can be sorted. For 'user' column, use User.username as
    # a column.
    column_sortable_list = ('title', ('user', 'user.username'), 'date')

    # Rename 'title' columns to 'Post Title' in list view
    column_labels = dict(title='Post Title')

    column_searchable_list = ('title', User.username, 'tags.name')

    column_filters = ('user',
                      'title',
                      'date',
                      'tags',
                      filters.FilterLike(Post.title, 'Fixed Title', options=(('test1', 'Test 1'), ('test2', 'Test 2'))))

    # Pass arguments to WTForms. In this case, change label for text field to
    # be 'Big Text' and add required() validator.
    form_args = dict(
                    text=dict(label='Big Text', validators=[validators.required()])
                )

    form_ajax_refs = {
        'user': {
            'fields': (User.username, User.email)
        },
        'tags': {
            'fields': (Tag.name,)
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, session):
        # Just call parent class with predefined model.
        super(PostAdmin, self).__init__(Post, session)


class TreeView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ['children', ]


# Create admin
admin = admin.Admin(app, name='Example: SQLAlchemy', template_mode='bootstrap3')

# Add views
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(sqla.ModelView(Tag, db.session))
admin.add_view(PostAdmin(db.session))
admin.add_view(TreeView(Tree, db.session))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Build a sample db on the fly, if one does not exist yet.
    app_dir = op.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    database_path = op.join(app_dir, app.config['DATABASE_FILE'])
    if not os.path.exists(database_path):
        build_sample_db()

    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle follows this format.

```
  -Main
   run.py
   -App
    -Static
    -Templates
     __init__.py
     config.py
     models.py
     views.py
```

run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
# app.config.from_pyfile('config_file.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Home!</a>'


import views
import models
```

config.py

```
import os
import configuration
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + 
app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
```

models.py

```
# Create models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


# Create M2M table
post_tags_table = db.Table('post_tags', db.Model.metadata,
                           db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')),
                           db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
                           )


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='posts')

    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=post_tags_table)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UserInfo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    key = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String(64))

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='info')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.key, self.value)


class Tree(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tree.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Tree', remote_side=[id], backref='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
# Customized User model admin
class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    inline_models = (UserInfo,)


# Customized Post model admin
class PostAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    # Visible columns in the list view
    column_exclude_list = ['text']

    # List of columns that can be sorted. For 'user' column, use User.username as
    # a column.
    column_sortable_list = ('title', ('user', 'user.username'), 'date')

    # Rename 'title' columns to 'Post Title' in list view
    column_labels = dict(title='Post Title')

    column_searchable_list = ('title', User.username, 'tags.name')

    column_filters = ('user',
                      'title',
                      'date',
                      'tags',
                      filters.FilterLike(Post.title, 'Fixed Title', options=(('test1', 'Test 1'), ('test2', 'Test 2'))))

    # Pass arguments to WTForms. In this case, change label for text field to
    # be 'Big Text' and add required() validator.
    form_args = dict(
                    text=dict(label='Big Text', validators=[validators.required()])
                )

    form_ajax_refs = {
        'user': {
            'fields': (User.username, User.email)
        },
        'tags': {
            'fields': (Tag.name,)
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, session):
        # Just call parent class with predefined model.
        super(PostAdmin, self).__init__(Post, session)


class TreeView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ['children', ]


# Create admin
admin = admin.Admin(app, name='Example: SQLAlchemy', template_mode='bootstrap3')

# Add views
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(sqla.ModelView(Tag, db.session))
admin.add_view(PostAdmin(db.session))
admin.add_view(TreeView(Tree, db.session))
```

Comment: It's a pity you left out the imports in models.py, as it is unclear how you import db there.

Comment: Also in the views what is the sqla object?